# Notepad++ bulk search and replace string with another string within the same line

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, bulk

I've got a file filled with a bunch of variable declarations looking like this:

```
//comment line
STR_first_string = "This is the first message to be shown.";
STR_another_message = "Second message here";
STR_string_message_three = "And the third one.";
STR_notification_number_four = "Bla bla yadder yadder";

//another comment line
...
```

Don't mind the inconsequent naming. It's just to show that the variable names are all different, except for the beginning `STR_`.

Now, I want to add something to every single line of the file, so that it looks like this:

```
//comment line
STR_first_string = "This is the first message to be shown."; publicVariable "STR_first_string";
STR_another_message = "Second message here"; publicVariable "STR_another_message";
STR_string_message_three = "And the third one."; publicVariable "STR_string_message_three";
STR_notification_number_four = "Bla bla yadder yadder"; publicVariable "STR_notification_number_four";

//another comment line
...
```

I informed myself about how to use RegEx in Notepad++. Basically, I intended to replace the terminating `;` with `publicVariable "` and then some fancy regex expression. But I haven't found something matching this particular problem. I'd be really happy if someone could help!

Regards,
Stacky

Comment: Could you check my answer? In case of problems leave comment under it. You can also leave info if it worked for you.

Comment: Checked it and it works perfectly! Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try replacing

```
((STR_\S+)\s*=\s*"([^"]|\\")*";)
```

with

```
\1 publicVariable "\2";
```

`\1` will represent part matched by entire regex and `\2` represents part matched by `(STR_\S+)`.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to replace:

```
(STR_\S+)\s*=\s*".*";
```

...with:

```
\0 publicVariable "\1";
```

Comment: +1, but while general idea is correct not all Notepad++ version support `\0` group reference so consider surrounding regex with parenthesis to place it in group 1 and as replacement use `\1 publicVariable "\2";`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the first regex considers the whole file as one single match, since it doesn't know what `*` is and thereby doesn't know that this regex should be used line by line. So this regex marks a text block, starting at the very first `STR_` and ends at the very last `;`.

Comment: @Stacky Strange, I don't have this problem. Well in that case don't use `".*"` but `"[^"]*"` (I assume that your strings don't have some inner escaped `"`).

Comment: Alright, the regex now recognizes every single line. But I believe, I use the replace term incorrectly. To clearify, the search statement marks the whole line. But I don't want to replace the whole line, I only want to add the variable name (beginning with `STR_`) to be in the quotes of the `publicVariable` declaration. And that still doesn't work yet.

Comment: @Stacky `the search statement marks the whole line. But I don't want to replace the whole line` That is OK. This regex should replace whole line with exactly same line plus additional values including variable name after `STR_`.

Comment: Using `\0 publicVariable "\1";` simply deletes the whole line. Using `\1 publicVariable "\2";` gives me the following result: `STR_first_string publicVariable "";` I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51294/discussion-between-stacky-and-pshemo)